# how to test `DID_FAIL_TO_RENEW` , `CANCEL` and any other event in sandbox environment

Tags: in-app-purchase

Now I am develop apple in app purchase, I read the docs and find out the sandbox environment only supprot `INITIAL_BUY，DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_PREF，DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS，DID_RENEW,INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL`. all this support event I have already handled. In the sandbox environmnet the apple server auto renew 6 times. In the subscribe mannagement page in settings->app store->sandbox account shows the all product unsubscribed after 6 times auto renew(I think in sandbox environment, the subscribe workflow are ended,so in the app we should tell user the subscribe ended), but in my app, I did not receive any cancel or other message to tell me the subscribetion cancelled. So what should I do to make the subscribe status keep the same?  How to test other events in sandbox environment? is there any way to do this? or I did not need test? or test in production environment? I am not sure my code logic always right, I am first time to develop in app purchase. What should I do to test all workflow works as expect? or I check the exipred time period in my database? This practice seems not a good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I am doing now is remember the user purchase product id and expired date in the user table, and check the expired user period to make sure the user is auto renew or cancel subscribed. saddly, I could not test other message type in sandbox environment until 2021.07.